# Storing form data after authentication middleware forces the user to log in

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7

I have authentication middleware on my store route.

If you are not logged in, it redirects you to the login page upon a forms submission.

You then log in, and are redirected automatically back to the page you were on (the form). How can I then get the forms data that was submitted before the log in?

I know data can be flashed to session. At what point should it occur and how can it be implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Just store data in Session. In your middleware, push the form data in the session:

   ```
   Session::push('formdata', $request->all());
   ```

   The form getting data from the session

   ```
   Session::get('formdata');
   ```
2. or you can store single values;

   ```
   Session::put('name', $request->name);
   Session::put('email', $request->email);
   ```

   ```
   Session::get('name');
   Session::get('email');
   ```

After log in:

```html
<form method="post" action="{{ url('/testing') }}">
    {{csrf_field() }}
     <input type="text" name="name" value="{{Session::get('name)}}">
     <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Does not answer the question - at what point should it occur and how can it be implemented

Comment: Why would that help?

Comment: in your middleware handle method

Comment: its very simple